# Broken Search Function

Tags: search

We are Using SharePoint 2013.  Immediately after rebooting the SharePoint server the search function works as it should.  10 to 15 minutes later, it fails and regardless of what you search for you get "Your search returned no results"

Any idea why?

Comment: If you use fiddler do you see the response with the search results? Try turning on verbose logging for search and look at what happens when a user with the issue loads the page.

Comment: Also, when search stops returning results, Check the status of Search Application Pool in IIS.

Comment: Im new to the Admin world; fiddler?  Any suggested reading?

Comment: http://www.asjava.com/tools/fiddler-tutorial-how-to-use-fiddler/ - Check this link for startup